# catching the warning message from aif web service

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, aif

I have a aif service in **ax 2012**.  I pass information into it from .net applications.  basically i'm posting to the general journal.  But when there is an error, say bad information being passed in, it returns a general error usually  **"error validating record"**.  But the warning message displays the actual reason why it caused an error such as the bad data.

Is there a way to catch and display the warning message.  I tried `exception::warning` but it just goes right to the `exception::error`.

```
catch (Exception::Error)
{
    throw Global::error("need to get warning");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope to understok the question.

If you ant get all *Warning message* from Infolog, I have a little solution.
You can take all Infolog created by system, look like :

```
InfologData             msg;
catch (Exception::Error)
{
     msg = infolog.infologData();
     infolog.import(msg); // HERE show all infolog - with INFO - Warning - Errors
     throw Global::error("Process Error");
}
```

It's not exactly request, but with this way can find all InfoLog displayed and warning too.

Good Work.

References : [Infolog-INFO](http://www.doens.be/2010/05/the-ax-infolog/) - [Infolog2String](http://daxmusings.codecrib.com/2011/10/get-infolog-details-from-code.html)

Comment: I would like to get it from AIF exception lists. under services and app integration framework

Answer (score 0):

From memory, but have you tried:

`throw error(AifUtil::getClrErrorMessage());`

Comment: Where in code are you trying to catch the error? The errors are throw to the infolog, so you actually have to cut them from there many times and/or I think the AIF error log may store them.

Comment: there is an aif error log that has them.. i want to grab it from there.. the last error and warning message.  i won't be reading or seeing any info log stuff

Comment: Hi @AlexKwitny i'm using this code but this return empty value, why could it be?

Comment: @Mumble that code is for catching `CLR` errors. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/how-to-catch-exceptions-thrown-from-clr-objects

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can help `throw error(CLRInterop::getLastException().ToString());`